# Nested Routing not working in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am having a problem in setting up nested routes.I am a beginner in React and exploring it.I am using Webpack for bundling and ruuning it on localhost.

**Project Structure**:-

```
project
 |---build
 |     |---index_bundle.js
 |     |--_index.html
 |---src
 |     |---components
 |----webpack.config.js
 |----package.json
 |----node_modules
 |----index.html
```

**Routes.js** file:-

```
  import CarDetail from './CarDetail.jsx';

   <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={Container}>
      <IndexRoute component={IndexPage} />
      <Route path="/route1" component={Component1}/>
      <Route path="/route2" component={Component2} />
      <Route path="/route3" component={Component3} />
      <Route path="cars/:id" component={CarDetail}/>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
    </Route>

  </Router>
```

**CarDetails.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class CarDetail extends Component {
 render(){
    return (<h1>{this.props.params.id}</h1>);
  }
}

export default CarDetail
```

When I am requesting http://localhost:8080/cars/5 ,it is showing an error:-
[image]

**webpack.config.js**:-

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HTMLWebpackPlugin= require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig= new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
  template:__dirname +'/index.html',
  filename:'index.html',
  inject:'body'
   });
 module.exports={
    entry:['./src/app-client.js'],
    output:{
     path:__dirname+'/build',
     filename:'index_bundle.js',
     publicPath:'/'
      },
devtool: 'inline-source-map',

devServer: {
 historyApiFallback: true
 },
module:{
 loaders:[

    { test:/\.jsx?$/,
      exclude:/node_modules/,
      loader:"babel-loader",
      query:{
        presets:["react","es2015","stage-2"]
      }
    }
   ]
  },
  plugins:[HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]
 }
```

**build/index.html**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
    <title>Working on React</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"   href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="react-app"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/build/index_bundle.js"></script>   <script type="text/javascript" src="/index_bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: The rest of the routes are working fine?

Comment: Can you show the HTML where you are loading in your index_bundle.js

Comment: The routes for components which I am defining in the same file are working fine but if I import some component and define a route for it is leading me to above error @RMontes13

Comment: The rest of routes are working fine.What i can sense the problem is when i browse http://localhost:8080/cars/5 ,webpack is loading http://localhost:8080/cars/index_bundle.js while the actual path is http://localhost:8080/index_bundle.js @RMontes13